# How are the parameters of a force field obtained for the bond angle HCH?

Tags: computational-chemistry

In my head, I can't see molecules that I could vary the HCH bond angle without varying other bond lengths, angles and dihedrals to build an energy vs. HCH bond angle curve.

If I vary a single HCH angle of a simple methane molecule, for example, I would automatically be varying the other HCH angles of that same molecule, which would affect the construction of the actual energy vs. HCH bond angle curve.

I may be talking nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a potential energy curve to fit a force field. I answered a [related question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/127823/5017) about fitting a force field from quantum calculations.

Let's assume you have a harmonic angle term. You could either do this in terms of the angle bending or the distance between the end atoms, but let's take the angle for our example:

$E_{angle} = k (\theta - \theta_0)^2$

The first parameter you need is the optimal angle $\theta_0$ which you can get from a geometry optimization, experiment, etc.

Your question stems from the second parameter, $k$ - the force constant for whatever this angle type happens to be (e.g. H-C-H in methane for your example).

There are a few ways to get the force constant, but it comes from the second derivative, right? So you can get that from a Hessian or vibrational calculation. My favorite discussions of this center around the "Badger's rule for angle force constants, e.g."

- "Maximally diagonal force constants in dependent angle-bending coordinates. II. Implications for the design of empirical force fields" [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1990**, 112, 12, 4710-4723](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00168a015)

> Unfortunately, most such force fields are defined in well-determined
>   sets of internal coordinates, whereas empirical potentials use larger
>   sets of dependent coordinates. This paper illustrates a unique
>   “localized” representation of the angle-deformation potential in
>   dependent coordinates which is exactly diagonal for in-plane bending
>   at trigonal-planar centers and is nearly diagonal for angle bending at
>   tetra coordinate centers.

Modern force field fitting methods typically use scripts that minimize the differences between an in-development parameter set and a set of Hessians and/or experimental data.

As I mentioned in the other question, there's a huge pile of such papers, many with code to derive force fields from quantum chemical data.

- QubeKit [*J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2019**, 59, 4, 1366-1381](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.8b00767) - code at [GitHub](https://github.com/qubekit/QUBEKit)
- QuickFF [*J. Comput. Chem*. **2015**, 36, 1015– 1027](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.23877) - code at [GitHub](https://github.com/molmod/QuickFF)
- ForceBalance [*J. Chem. Theory Compute.* **2013**, 9, 1, 452-460](https://doi.org/10.1021/ct300826t) and [J. Phys. Chem. Lett. 2014, 5, 11, 1885-1891](https://doi.org/10.1021/jz500737m) - code at [GitHub](https://github.com/leeping/forcebalance)
- ForceFit [*J. Comput. Chem.*, **2010** 31: 2307-2316](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.21523)
- Parfit [*J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2017**, 57, 3, 391-396](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.6b00654) - code at [GitHub](https://github.com/fzahari/ParFit)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, Geoff Hutchison! I am very grateful for your help. As this area is new to me, it has been difficult for me to understand some things for now.
The first idea I had was to derive the parameters of the force field through potential energy curves. Some things are explicit and I am managing to solve it in Gaussian, for example. Others don't.

Comment: Hutcison I was thinking about one thing ... Every scan that we perform to obtain the energy curve (varying bond length, bond angle and dihedral), indirectly we would be changing the non-bonded interaction parameters.
That would be a limitation, right? It would be practically impossible to obtain the isolated parameters of bond length, bond angle and dihedral.
Did I say any nonsense?

Comment: @EmersonPL - please read the 1990 Halgren paper. It goes into the issues of 'separability' between QM / experiment and the typical design of force fields.